Problem 7.4 in Billingsley Probability and Measure, 3rd Edition
I'm working on the following problem in Billingsley's Probability and Measure, 3rd edition:
Let $D_n$ be 1 or 0 according as $X_{2n-1}\ne X_{2n}$ or not, and let $M_k$ be the time of the $k$th 1---the smallest $n$ such that $\sum^n_{i=1}D_i=k$. Let $Z_k=X_{2M_k}$. In other words, look at successive nonoverlapping pairs $(X_{2n-1}, X_{2n})$, discard accordant pairs $(X_{2n-1}=X_{2n})$, and keep the second element of discordant $(X_{2n-1}\ne X_{2n})$ pairs. Show that this process simulates a fair coin: $Z_1,Z_2,...$ are i.i.d. random variables, and $P[Z_k=1]=P[Z_k=-1]=\frac{1}{2}$, whatever $p$ may be. Follow the proof of Theorem 7.1.
The set up is $p\in[0,1]$, and the $X_n=1$ with probability $p$, and $X_n=-1$ with probability $1-p$.
For this problem, I'm not sure why the case $p=1$ is not a counterexample to this problem. For, if $p=1$, then $M_k=\infty$ with probability 1, and so the $Z_k's$ will not equal either $1$ or $-1$ with probability 1.
I'm not looking for a solution to this problem. I'm more so trying to understand if the statement is true and where my misunderstanding lies.
Thanks!

It's not uncommon to exclude both $p=1$ and $p=0$ from such problems.

what's the context?!
